# SSRS combining multiple rows from multiple columns into one row

Tags: sql, reporting-services, group-by, visual-studio-2008, pivot

We need to check requirements for students exams (e.g. extra time allocated (A), word processor (B), reader (C), and other). Currently the SQL pumps out the information like this:

```
Student | Exam Requirements
---------------------------
   1    |        A
   1    |        B
   2    |        A
   2    |        B
   2    |        C
   3    |        B
   4    |        B
   4    |        C
   5    |        A
   6    |        D
   7    |        E
   8    |        F
```

and I need to display it in SSRS like this:

### Student | Requirement A | Requirement B | Requirement C | Other requirement

```
   1    |       Y       |       Y       |       -       |       -        
   2    |       Y       |       Y       |       Y       |       -        
   3    |       -       |       Y       |       -       |       -        
   4    |       -       |       Y       |       Y       |       -       
   5    |       Y       |       -       |       -       |       -       
   6    |       -       |       -       |       -       |       D       
   7    |       -       |       -       |       -       |       E       
   8    |       -       |       -       |       -       |       F
```

Currently, as the row group is grouped on the Student, my table only shows a 'Y' in the column for Requirement A. If I group it on requirement then it creates as many rows as the student has requirements.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    student,
    coalesce(max(case when exam_requirements = 'A' then 'Y' end), '-') requirement_a,
    coalesce(max(case when exam_requirements = 'B' then 'Y' end), '-') requirement_b,
    coalesce(max(case when exam_requirements = 'C' then 'Y' end), '-') requirement_c,
    coalesce(max(case when exam_requirements not in ('A', 'B', 'C') then exam_requirements end), '-') other_requirement
from mytable
group by student
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the dataset with the following query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Student int, Requirement varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1, 'A'),(1, 'B'),(2, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(2, 'C'),(3, 'B'),(4, 'B'),(4, 'C'),(5, 'A'),(6, 'D'),(7, 'E'),(8, 'F')
```

Then used this dataset in the report

```
SELECT 
    Student
    , CASE WHEN Requirement IN ('A','B','C') THEN Requirement ELSE 'Other' END AS ExamRequirement
    , CASE WHEN Requirement IN ('A','B','C') THEN 'Y' ELSE Requirement END AS reportvalue
    FROM @t
```

This gives the following output

[image]

I then added a Matrix to the report, set the row group by Student and the column group by ExamRequirement and the [data] to reportValue. The design looks like this

[image]

The final output looks like this

[image]

Comment: This one would work but I need the actual data to be shown for the 'other' entries (e.g. D, E, F, etc)

Comment: The final output (last screenshot) shows exactly what your question stated was the requirement. The values D, E and F are shown in the 'Other' column